# LibVLCSharp - WinUI - Memory Leak?

Tags: c#, winui-3, libvlcsharp

LibVLCSharp is now available for WinUI, and its documentation can be found [here](https://mfkl.github.io/2023/04/04/introducing-libvlcsharp-for-winui.html).

This is great news, and thank you for sharing it.

I am experiencing an issue with memory usage. Whenever I start and stop the player, not all of the memory is released, and as a result, the memory usage keeps growing..

I tried disposing of the player and the library, but this is not working.

```
private void MovieWindow_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
{
    mp.Stopped += (s, e) =>
    {
        grid.Children.Remove(VideoView);
    };
    mp.Stop();

    var toDispose = mp;
    var toDispose2 = libvlc;
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        toDispose?.Dispose();
        toDispose2?.Dispose();
    });
}
```

I have a simple sample available [here](https://github.com/Franck-E/LibVLCSharp.WinUI).
Any suggestions on the best approach?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't dispose in a task, some objects require all calls to happen on the (here UI) thread that created them. However, that doesn't change anything here. I've tested in release, added a call to `GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Aggressive, true, true);` after each stop and I still miss ~5Mb at each run. Maybe that's expected for some reason, you should ask the guys who develop that nuget, seems to be @mfkl

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue Simon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you ran into the issue that mfkl saw during development : https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/pull/301

If that's the same leak, it was fixed in libvlc : https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/merge_requests/3441

However, the fix has not been released yet, it will be in the next libvlc nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that a fix is on the way.